# Excel conditional format entire column based on cell value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet that has a 7000 rows. My sheet does have a header row. Column G is not supposed to have any cell with a value greater then 1000. I want to highlight red the cells with these "bad values". This I accomplished with the conditional formatting cell value greater then 1000 and applied it to G2:G10000. even though I would love to apply this G:G, so that I don't limit this to just 10,000 rows (there may be rows ith future then the current 7,000).

My bigger issue is that to highlight that column G has a "bad" cell(s) I would lime to highlight all of column G.

I tried using  a conditional formatting formula = $G2>1000 and applied it to G:G it only highlighted the cell. I tried = $A2>1000 and applied it to G:G, It highlighted the entire column always even when the condition wasn't met.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with a COUNTIF formula. I mis-read and did this for a value greater than or equal 10,000. Take out one of my ZEROs in the equation!

As the solution stands, if any cell in column G exceeds (or equals) 10,000, the entire column will highlight.

[image]

[image]